# What does it mean $A\times\mathbb{R}^J=?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a doubt about measure theory that I think it has to do with the Cartesian product. What does it mean to have a projection of a given set like $A\times\mathbb{R}^J=?$ Is the result  the combination of $(a_1,a_2...a_n)\in A$(n is finite) with evey element of $\mathbb{R}$ or is the combination with only $n$ number of  elements of $\mathbb{R}$?  Note: $J=\begin{align}\begin{cases}\mathbb{R}_+ 
\\\mathbb{R}\end{cases}\end{align}$ in this case.

I am studying the Kolmogorov extension theorem, and the proof is making use of it. I could perhaps write the proof but on my notebook it is too lengthy. I am following *Introduction to Measure and Integration by Taylor*.

Comment: It says $A$ and not $A^j$ (why do you have the tuple there?). Also, you might tell us what $J$ is. But a typical element of this cartesian product is $(a,f)$ where $a\in A$ and $f:J\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Exactly that what I saw. Could explain it to me please? I mean $J\in\mathbb{R}$. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't tell what you're asking. It seemed @martin.koeberl's comment was close, but you ask for explanation without saying what you're unclear on. All any of us know is that you encountered the expression "$A\times\mathbb{R}^J$" in one proof of the Kolmogorov extension theorem, and that you don't understand *something* about it.

Comment: I have found out that you can call a projection something like this:$ A_1\times\mathbb{R}^{j-1}=A^j$ a projection of $A_1$ dimension to $A_j$ in which $j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A_1$ is a set on one dimensional space. Let's say $A$ is finite and has $n$ elements What I want to understand is if this product comprehends the Cartesian product of all elements of $A$ times all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ or the Cartesian product of all elements of $A$ times  $n$(finite) number of elements of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ah, assuming $j$ is a positive integer, then the elements of the product are single elements of $A$ paired with $j$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb{R}$---the exponential/product notation borrows its convention from the arithmetic convention that exponents associate more strongly than multiplication, IME.

Comment: You mean $n$-tuples, right?